# How can I count the number of items using the FIND function in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab, count, find

How can I use the function `FIND` to count the number of items of a given value instead of using a loop? For example, in the array `item` below there are 3 occurrences of the number 23, 2 occurrences of the number 22, and 2 occurrences of the number 20.

```
....
for i=2:n
    if item(i-1)~=item(i)
        nItem21(i)=1;
    else 
        nItem21(i)=nItem21(i-1)+1;
    end
end

item Num
23   2
23   4
23   6
22   3
22   1
20   6
20   8
```

Comment: What should happen if item is `[10,20,20,10]`? If the counts should be `[1,2,1]`, my solution is correct, if the counts should be `[2,2]` it's @Doresoom's

Comment: @Jonas: I think your solution is more versatile. With the addition of a sort command, yours can handle either situation. +1

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do the following: identify where the value of `item` changes, then use diff to get the counts.

```
item = [
23   
23   
23   
22   
22   
20   
20];

% find the 'last' entries of each consecutive group of numbers
chgRowNum = [find(item(1:end-1) ~= item(2:end);length(item)]; 

counts = diff([0;chgRowNum]);

correspondingItems = item(chgRowNum);
```

Answer (score 2):

[`Find`](http://www.mathworks.com/access/helpdesk/help/techdoc/ref/find.html) returns the indices of nonzero elements in an array. If you want a count of all the occurrences of your elements (assuming they're integers), you can use the [`hist`](http://www.mathworks.com/access/helpdesk/help/techdoc/ref/hist.html) function. By assigning an output, it won't plot a histogram. Instead it will return an array of occurrences.

```
x=[20 23 20 22 23 21 23 22];
bins=min(x):max(x);
count=hist(x,bins);
list=unique(x);
```

Now `count` contains the number of occurrences, and `list` contains each unique array element.
To get rid of zero count elements:

```
idx=find(count);
count=count(idx);
```

or the one line option (without using find):

```
count=count(count~=0);
```

Answer (score 2):

Just for completeness I would use the `histc` function.

```
item = [
23   
23   
23   
22   
22   
20   
20];
%get the unique items
[uni_items, minds, uinds] = unique(item);
%count them
counts = histc(uinds, 1:numel(uni_items));
%put them in the original order
ocounts = counts(minds);
```

This takes care of them not being in order or if they're not integers.

Answer (score 2):

Another option for this situation is to use the function [ACCUMARRAY](http://www.mathworks.com/access/helpdesk/help/techdoc/ref/accumarray.html), which wouldn't require that the list be sorted first. This is particularly useful if you were to have a set of numbers in `item` that span a range of `1:N`, where `N` is any integer value. Here's how it would work for your example:

```
item = [23; 23; 23; 22; 22; 20; 20];  %# A column vector of integers
counts = accumarray(item,1);          %# Collect counts of each item into
                                      %#   a 23-by-1 array
```

The array `counts` is a 23-by-1 array where the elements indexed by 23, 22, and 20 contain the counts 3, 2, and 2, respectively. All the other elements are 0 (i.e. there are no counts found for the numbers 1 through 19 or 21).

If you want to get a list of the unique values in `item` and their corresponding counts, you can do this using the function [UNIQUE](http://www.mathworks.com/access/helpdesk/help/techdoc/ref/unique.html):

```
>> uniqueValues = unique(item)  %# Get the unique values in item

uniqueValues =

    20
    22
    23

>> counts = counts(uniqueValues)  %# Get just the counts for each unique value

counts =

     2
     2
     3
```